# mysql trigger stored trigger is already used by statement which invoked stored trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

I want to set up a trigger so that if on an update the prediction field is = 3 then the trigger changes the value to 4 and saves it in the database. The trigger is below.

For some reason I keep getting an error saying:

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'tzanalytic\_forecast\_cached' in stored 
function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked 
this stored function/trigger.
```

Is this set up the right way?

```
delimiter $$ 
CREATE TRIGGER no_BoW BEFORE UPDATE ON t FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN set @prediction = new.prediction; 
UPDATE t SET t.prediction = (SELECT IF(@prediction = '3', '4', @prediction)) WHERE t.event_id = new.event_id AND t.price_tier = new.price_tier; END;
$$ delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 42):

MySQL triggers can't manipulate the table they are assigned to. All other major DBMS support this feature so hopefully MySQL will add this support soon.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,122354,240978#msg-240978

Comment: And me, that's a very annoying bug

Comment: everyday i hate mysql more

Comment: SI this still true on version 5.5?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need to ensure that you don't have other procedures or functions that perform updates on the table that this particular procedure is assigned to or you end up in a recursion. For instance

```
create trigger trig1 After update on table1 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE table2 SET colum1 = column1 + 1
END;

create trigger trig2 After update on table2 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
UPDATE table1 SET colum2 = column2 + 1
END;
```

This will end up in a recursion so beware of the existing stored procedures and functions.