# MySQL Trigger with cursor returning error 1442 or not having an effect at all

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently using a database to handle an ingame inventory. 
I have written a trigger in mySQL to try and have the items combine every time a new one is inserted in the table. Each item has two components.

I am doing something very wrong, but I can't see what it might be. This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `onitempickup` AFTER INSERT ON 
`inventory` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
BEGIN

DECLARE done boolean DEFAULT false;

DECLARE Item2Combine VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE MadefromResult1 VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE MadefromResult2 VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE ComboItemName1 VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE ComboItemName2 VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE in_itemname VARCHAR(10);


DECLARE Madefromcheck1Cursor cursor for 
SELECT name, madefrom1 FROM item WHERE madefrom2 = in_itemname;

DECLARE Madefromcheck2Cursor cursor for
SELECT name, madefrom2 FROM i``tem WHERE madefrom1 = in_itemname;

DECLARE ItemToCombineCursor cursor for 
SELECT Item from inventory;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

SET in_itemname = NEW.Item;


OPEN MadefromCheck1Cursor;
OPEN MadefromCheck2Cursor;
OPEN ItemToCombineCursor;

read_loop: LOOP

FETCH ItemToCombineCursor INTO Item2Combine;
FETCH Madefromcheck1Cursor INTO ComboItemName1, MadefromResult1;
FETCH MadefromCheck2Cursor INTO ComboItemName2, MadefromResult2;

IF done THEN
LEAVE read_loop;

ELSEIF Item2Combine = MadefromResult1 THEN 
INSERT INTO Inventory(Item) VALUES(ComboItemName1);
DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE Item = in_itemname;
DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE Item = Item2Combine;
LEAVE read_loop;

ELSEIF Item2Combine = MadefromResult2 THEN INSERT 
INTO Inventory(Item) VALUES(ComboItemName2);
DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE Item = in_itemname;
DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE Item = Item2Combine;
LEAVE read_loop;

ELSE
ITERATE read_loop;

END IF;

END LOOP read_loop;

CLOSE Madefromcheck1Cursor;
CLOSE Madefromcheck2Cursor;
CLOSE ItemToCombineCursor;

END
```

I have tried to change it to act before the insert to no avail, as the procedure did not even execute. I currently get an error 1442 implying that I have an infinite loop somewhere according to many questions here on stack overflow, but I don't see where.

I appreciate any help. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Your processing a trigger on a table - which is inserting a record into that table, this may cause the trigger to be fired ;)

Comment: Oh boy. Thank you for the insight, spent more time on this than I'd like to admit. You got me unstuck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the real cause of mysql error 1442?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756454/what-is-the-real-cause-of-mysql-error-1442)