# Workaround for MySQL trigger error when updating table which is already being used

Tags: mysql

I created a trigger which throws an error whenever new entry is stored. Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `htmlid` BEFORE INSERT ON `makelist_food`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (NEW.html_id IS NULL) THEN
  INSERT INTO makelist_food SET html_id = CONCAT('f', NEW.id);
END IF;
END
```

And the error is: #1442 - Can't update table 'makelist_food' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

There are many discussions out there about this error but I haven't found any solution or workaround. Here is an answer from 2010 [stackoverflow.com/questions/1582683/mysql-trigger-stored-trigger-is-already-used-by-statement-which-invoked-stored-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582683/mysql-trigger-stored-trigger-is-already-used-by-statement-which-invoked-stored-t) which states that this is simply not supported in MySQL.

Since this is more than 2 years old answer I was wondering if SO knows some workaround for this problem. I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you by any chance mean

```
IF (NEW.html_id IS NULL) THEN
    SET NEW.html_id = CONCAT('f', NEW.id);
END IF;
```

Comment: You are right, that was the problem. Thanks! There is an issue with this trigger though. It always updates html_id field to the value f0. I expected it would pick up the id of a newly created record and concatenate it with f. But I guess this is a whole new question.

Comment: I don't think that would be possible, the auto_increment id does't exist yet at that point. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211792/mysql-trigger-to-update-a-field-to-the-value-of-id)

Comment: You might be able to hack it up using a 'manual auto increment' but that might slow it down and create other problems.