# How to Update same table on deletion in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1442

In my database I have a table `Employee` that has recursive association (an employee can be boss of other employee):

```
create table if not exists `employee` (

  `SSN` varchar(64) not null,
  `name` varchar(64) default null,
  `designation` varchar(128) not null,
  `MSSN` varchar(64) default null, 
  primary key (`ssn`),
  constraint `fk_manager_employee`  foreign key (`mssn`) references employee(ssn)

) engine=innodb default charset=latin1;
```

```
mysql> describe Employee;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SSN         | varchar(64)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name        | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| designation | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| MSSN        | varchar(64)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then inserts:

```
mysql> insert into Employee values
    -> ("1", "A", "OWNER",  NULL), 
    -> ("2", "B", "BOSS",   "1"),
    -> ("3", "C", "WORKER", "2"),
    -> ("4", "D", "BOSS",   "2"),
    -> ("5", "E", "WORKER", "4"),
    -> ("6", "F", "WORKER", "1"),
    -> ("7", "G", "WORKER", "4")
    -> ;
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now I have following hierarchical relation (owner > boss > worker) among the rows in table:

```
     A
    / \
   B   F
  / \
 c   D
    / \
   G   E
```

Following is Select statement for table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM Employee;
+-----+------+-------------+------+
| SSN | name | designation | MSSN |
+-----+------+-------------+------+
| 1   | A    | OWNER       | NULL |
| 2   | B    | BOSS        | 1    |  
| 3   | C    | WORKER      | 2    |  
| 4   | D    | BOSS        | 2    |  
| 5   | E    | WORKER      | 4    |   
| 6   | F    | WORKER      | 1    |  
| 7   | G    | WORKER      | 4    |  
+-----+------+-------------+------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, I want to impose a constraint like : `If any employee (BOSS) deleted then new BOSS of workers under him become immediate BOSS of deleted employee (Old BOSS)`. e.g. If I delete `D` then `B` Become BOSS of `G` and `E`.

For that I also written a **Trigger** as follows:

```
mysql>  DELIMITER $$
mysql>        CREATE
    ->        TRIGGER `Employee_before_delete` BEFORE DELETE
    ->          ON `Employee`
    ->          FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    ->          UPDATE Employee
    ->          SET MSSN=old.MSSN
    ->          WHERE MSSN=old.MSSN; 
    ->        END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.07 sec)

mysql>        DELIMITER ;
```

But When I perform some deletion:

```
mysql> DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN='4';
ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'Employee' in stored function/trigger
because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored 
function/trigger.
```

I [learn here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582683/mysql-trigger-stored-trigger-is-already-used-by-statement-which-invoked-stored-t/2314264#2314264) that `this trigger is not possible` because `In MySQL triggers can't manipulate the table they are assigned to`.

Is there some **other possible way to do this?** Is it possible using `Nested Query`? Can some one suggest me other method ? A suggestion would be enough but should be efficient.

**EDIT**:
 I got answers: 
 Instead of trigger a `stored procedure` or `two consecutive queries` is possible.
 [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487010/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql/13487164#13487164) and [second](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29047/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql/29076#29076).

The Solution I wrote for this problem as below, **Working Well!**:

- A a helper signal function as I am writing for `MYSQL version older then 5.5`.

> DELIMITER //
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE `my_signal`(in_errortext VARCHAR(255))
> BEGIN
>     SET @sql=CONCAT('UPDATE `', in_errortext, '` SET x=1');
>     PREPARE my_signal_stmt FROM @sql;
>     EXECUTE my_signal_stmt;
>     DEALLOCATE PREPARE my_signal_stmt;
> END//
> ```

- A Stored Procedure to delete employee from `Employee` Table.

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE delete_employee(IN dssn varchar(64))
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE empDesignation varchar(128);
>     DECLARE empSsn         varchar(64);
>     DECLARE empMssn        varchar(64);
>      SELECT SSN, designation, MSSN  INTO empSsn, empDesignation, empMssn 
>      FROM Employee 
>      WHERE SSN = dssn;
>
>    IF (empSsn IS NOT NULL) THEN
>     CASE       
>            WHEN empDesignation = 'OWNER' THEN 
>                CALL my_signal('Error: OWNER can not deleted!');
>
>            WHEN empDesignation = 'WORKER' THEN 
>             DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN = empSsn;               
>
>            WHEN empDesignation = 'BOSS' THEN 
>                BEGIN 
>                    UPDATE Employee
>                    SET MSSN = empMssn
>                    WHERE MSSN = empSsn;
>
>                 DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN = empSsn;                   
>
>                END;
>     END CASE;
>    ELSE 
>                CALL my_signal('Error: Not a valid row!');
>    END IF;
> END//
> ```
>
> DELIMITER ;

Comment: Can you try the following? It looks rather too simple for your requirement specially in terms of having a dynamic deletion...


`update Employee`

`set MSSN=(select mssn from employee`

`where ssn = '4');`

`delete from employee where ssn = 4;`

Comment: @bonCodigo: You mean two consecutive query for deletion. May be considered...But I have to think about this -Thanks!

Comment: Yeah two consective queries. It also seems that EntityFramework in sql server provides Repository Pattern - it could allow you to make the repository's delete function recursive via a stored procedure. I haven't done it myself personally. Perhaps you could mimic the same here. Interesting question +1

Comment: `Please add a comment if some one vote-downs`

Comment: Also See : [**BOTH SOLUTIONS**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518890/which-update-is-faster-using-join-or-sequential)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html):

```
UPDATE b
   SET b.mssn = a.mssn
  FROM EMPLOYEE a
  JOIN EMPLOYEE b ON b.mssn = a.ssn
 WHERE a.ssn = @deletedBoss

DELETE FROM employee WHERE ssn = @deletedBoss
```

With a stored procedure, you can simply delete the rows you want, and after that, update the same table. That should prevent the error message.

Comment: You mean Instead of Trigger, I should call Procedure that delete and update both...I would try.-thanks

Comment: Yes, you can run as many statements as you want within a stored procedure. You can perform any CRUD statement on any tables all within a single stored procedure. And if the answer does help, do upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: @OMGPonies: Thanks! ...Add some contact in your profile..I was trying to contact you.

Comment: @It's Your Fault : Thanks to you too!

Comment: @OMGPonies Hi, It seems you are of-line.. I need you help on this question: [MySQL trigger On Insert/Update events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975877/mysql-trigger-on-insert-update-events) I tried to answer and I guess it should work but it doesn't works. Can you add an answer there.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD, Isn't it better to do an update first instead of delete? (e.g. if it's foreign key bounded)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a hard delete, do a soft delete. Add is_deleted column and set it to 1 if you want to delete the row. Create after_update trigger on the table.

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE
    TRIGGER `Employee_after_update` AFTER UPDATE
      ON `Employee`
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      UPDATE Employee
      ...............
      WHERE NEW.is_deleted=1; 
      DELETE FROM Employee WHERE NEW.is_deleted=1
    END$$
```

I am not sure that you can update the same table for after_{insert,delete,update}. Please check this

Comment: This is a suggestion, not an answer.