# Which update is faster using join or sequential?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-5.0

This question is in sequence of my [previous **Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487010/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql) required update same table on deletion a row.

I could write two solutions using **Stored Procedure** instead of trigger or nested-query .

Both use a helper function [my_signal(msg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487010/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql).

A Stored Procedure to delete employee from `Employee` Table.

- **Fist Solution**: use `UPDATE` rows in table, **without join operation**:

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE delete_employee(IN dssn varchar(64))
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE empDesignation varchar(128);
>     DECLARE empSsn         varchar(64);
>     DECLARE empMssn        varchar(64);
>      SELECT SSN, designation, MSSN  INTO empSsn, empDesignation, empMssn 
>      FROM Employee 
>      WHERE SSN = dssn;
>
>    IF (empSsn IS NOT NULL) THEN
>     CASE       
>            WHEN empDesignation = 'OWNER' THEN 
>                CALL my_signal('Error: OWNER can not deleted!');
>
>            WHEN empDesignation = 'WORKER' THEN 
>             DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN = empSsn;               
>
>            WHEN empDesignation = 'BOSS' THEN 
>                BEGIN 
>                    UPDATE Employee
>                    SET MSSN = empMssn
>                    WHERE MSSN = empSsn;
>
>                 DELETE FROM Employee WHERE SSN = empSsn;                   
>
>                END;
>     END CASE;
>    ELSE 
>                CALL my_signal('Error: Not a valid row!');
>    END IF;
> END//
> ```

- **Second solution:** as I was suggested in my previous question using `INNER JOIN`

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE delete_employee(IN dssn varchar(64))
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE empDesignation varchar(128);
>     DECLARE empSsn         varchar(64);
>     DECLARE empMssn        varchar(64);
>       SELECT SSN, designation, MSSN  INTO empSsn, empDesignation, empMssn 
>       FROM Employee 
>       WHERE SSN = dssn;
>
>    IF (empSsn IS NOT NULL) THEN
>        IF (empDesignation = 'OWNER') THEN 
>         CALL my_signal('Error: OWNER can not deleted!');
>        END IF;
>
>        UPDATE `Employee` A INNER JOIN `Employee` B ON A.SSN= B.MSSN
>        SET B.MSSN = A.MSSN WHERE A.SSN = empSsn;
>
>        DELETE FROM `Employee` WHERE SSN = empSsn;
>    ELSE 
>        CALL my_signal('Error: Not a valid row!');
>    END IF;    
> END//
> ```

I read [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/c0005283.htm) that using join is efficient for Efficient SELECT. But my problem includes only one table and I feel my solution(first) is much efficient than second because join will consume memory comparatively.

Please suggest me which is better and efficient, if `Employee table` is sufficiently large. **Which is better for me? Reason**

**EDIT:**  I checked for small table consist of 7 rows only, and both solution take same time.

```
mysql> CALL delete_employee(4);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.09 sec)
```

I know SQL function behaves non-deterministically because table heuristics. Which choice is better? Either if you have some idea How query can be further optimised.

Comment: **READ THIS** [**QUESTION**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487010/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

After a while of thinking I am almost sure it doesn't make a difference, first solution may be even slightly slower, but in a not measurable dimension.

First intention would be, that the first solution is faster because you first fetch data by id and update only if nessesary.

But MySQL internally does nothing else in the `UPDATE .. JOIN` statement, just internally and as a result of this probably more efficiently as well.

Your first solution doesn't catch a default case - what happens if I neither get `WORKER` or `BOSS`?

Also your execution time (0.09s) is extremely high, which can't be explained with what I know about your database so far.

Did you set any index?

**EDIT:**

After looking at the [table structure you've posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487010/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql) 
I have some improvement offers for the structure itself.

**1.** Use type `int` when you are storing `integer values`. The database can handle integer way more efficient

**2.** Why generate `SSN` by yourself? Using `auto_increment` on the `PRIMARY KEY` is much simpler to handle and saves you a lot of work when you add new employees

```
ALTER TABLE `Employee`
    CHANGE `SSN` `SSN` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    CHANGE `MSSN` `MSSN` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    ADD KEY `KEY_Employee_MSSN` ( `MSSN` );
```

**3.** Do you use the name for lookups? If so, it needs to be unique as well

```
ALTER TABLE `Employee`
    ADD UNIQUE KEY `UNI_KEY_Employee` ( `name` );
```

**4.** Do you have a fixed range of designations? enum forces the input to be one of the defined values

```
ALTER TABLE `Employee`
    CHANGE `designation` `designation` ENUM( 'BOSS', 'WORKER' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'WORKER',
    ADD KEY `KEY_Employee_designation` ( `designation` );
```

**Final structure**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN `Employee`;

+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| SSN         | int(11)               | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(64)           | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| designation | enum('BOSS','WORKER') | NO   | MUL | WORKER  |                |
| MSSN        | int(11)               | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This [**Database**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487010/how-to-update-same-table-on-deletion-in-mysql) is consist of just seven tuples!