# MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am running a MySQL Query. But when a new row is added from form input I get this error:

```
Error: Can't update table 'brandnames' in stored function/trigger because it is 
already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

From the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `capital` AFTER INSERT ON `brandnames`
FOR EACH
ROW UPDATE brandnames
SET bname = CONCAT( UCASE( LEFT( bname, 1 ) ) , LCASE( SUBSTRING( bname, 2 ) ) )
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: what are you trying to do with your trigger? Table schema, example data and example INSERT query would help a lot

Comment: I want to change the case to upper case of an enrered row value. So I want this trigger to automatically do this for me everytime a row is entered. I don't want javascript.

Comment: @EricLeschinski I don't know what he did on that question.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You cannot change a table while the `INSERT` trigger is firing. The `INSERT` might do some locking which could result in a deadlock. Also, updating the table from a trigger would then cause the same trigger to fire again in an infinite recursive loop. Both of these reasons are why **MySQL** prevents you from doing this.

However, depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can access the new values by using `NEW.fieldname` or even the old values *--if doing an `UPDATE`--* with `OLD`.

If you had a row named `full_brand_name` and you wanted to use the first two letters as a short name in the field `small_name` you could use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `capital` BEFORE INSERT ON `brandnames`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.short_name = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(NEW.full_name,1)) , LCASE(SUBSTRING(NEW.full_name,2)))
END
```

Comment: As referenced in another SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582683/mysql-trigger-stored-trigger-is-already-used-by-statement-which-invoked-stored-t), MySQL doesn't (yet?) support this feature (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,122354,240978#msg-240978), even though its competitors do.

Comment: @Steve I am getting the same problem. when I am trying: update employee_audit set lastName = 'Sharma' where employeeNumber =112;

Comment: i would like to implement for diff duration clock , thanks ...

Comment: but dunno why didnt work -> update the field of NEW.short_name hm ```delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER person_bi BEFORE INSERT
ON person
FOR EACH ROW
IF NEW.clock_out_time != null THEN
 SET NEW.name='helo';
END IF; //
delimiter ;```

Answer (score 9):

The correct syntax is:

```
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.bname = CONCAT( UCASE( LEFT( NEW.bname, 1 ) )
                                   , LCASE( SUBSTRING( NEW.bname, 2 ) ) )
```

Comment: MySQL says: Updating of new row is not allowed in after trigger. :(

Comment: Sorry, you need to change it from AFTER INSERT to BEFORE INSERT, as in Steve's answer

Answer (score 5):

A "BEFORE-INSERT"-trigger is the only way to realize same-table updates on an insert, and is only possible from MySQL 5.5+. However, the value of an auto-increment field is only available to an "AFTER-INSERT" trigger - it defaults to 0 in the BEFORE-case. Therefore the following example code which would set a previously-calculated surrogate key value based on the auto-increment value `id` will compile, but not actually work since NEW.id will always be 0:

```
create table products(id int not null auto_increment, surrogatekey varchar(10), description text);
create trigger trgProductSurrogatekey before insert on product
for each row set NEW.surrogatekey = 
  (select surrogatekey from surrogatekeys where id = NEW.id);
```

Answer (score 5):

@gerrit_hoekstra wrote: "However, the value of an auto-increment field is only available to an "AFTER-INSERT" trigger - it defaults to 0 in the BEFORE-case."

That is correct but you can select the auto-increment field value that will be inserted by the subsequent INSERT quite easily. This is an example that works:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `lgffin`.`variable_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT 
ON `variable` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.prefixed_id = CONCAT(NEW.fixed_variable, (SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
                                                FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                                                WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'lgffin'
                                                AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'variable'));      
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and fix by add "new." before the field is updated. And I post full trigger here for someone to want to write a trigger

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `nc`$$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `nhachung_province_count_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `nhachung` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    DECLARE slug_province VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE slug_district VARCHAR(128);

    IF old.status!=new.status THEN  /* neu doi status */
        IF new.status="Y" THEN
            UPDATE province SET `count`=`count`+1 WHERE id = new.district_id;
        ELSE 
            UPDATE province SET `count`=`count`-1 WHERE id = new.district_id;
        END IF;
    ELSEIF old.province_id!=new.province_id THEN /* neu doi province_id + district_id */

        UPDATE province SET `count`=`count`+1 WHERE id = new.province_id; /* province_id */
        UPDATE province SET `count`=`count`-1 WHERE id = old.province_id;
        UPDATE province SET `count`=`count`+1 WHERE id = new.district_id; /* district_id */
        UPDATE province SET `count`=`count`-1 WHERE id = old.district_id;

        SET slug_province = ( SELECT slug FROM province WHERE id= new.province_id LIMIT 0,1 );
        SET slug_district = ( SELECT slug FROM province WHERE id= new.district_id LIMIT 0,1 );
        SET new.prov_dist_url=CONCAT(slug_province, "/", slug_district);

    ELSEIF old.district_id!=new.district_id THEN 

        UPDATE province SET `count`=`count`+1 WHERE id = new.district_id;
        UPDATE province SET `count`=`count`-1 WHERE id = old.district_id;

        SET slug_province = ( SELECT slug FROM province WHERE id= new.province_id LIMIT 0,1 );
        SET slug_district = ( SELECT slug FROM province WHERE id= new.district_id LIMIT 0,1 );
        SET new.prov_dist_url=CONCAT(slug_province, "/", slug_district);

    END IF;


    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this help someone