# Insert trigger updating certain columns

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

So, I have a table, described via the SQL given below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
`e_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`e_username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`left_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`right_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`e_ssn` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`e_first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`e_last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`e_address` text NOT NULL,
`e_location` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `e_id` (`e_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `e_username` (`e_username`)
)
```

And it has the given data

```
INSERT INTO `employees` (`e_id`, `e_username`, `left_id`, `right_id`, `e_ssn`, `e_first_name`, `e_last_name`, `e_address`, `e_location`) VALUES
(1, '100884', 1, 8, 444444444, 'James', 'Burnbridge', '1123 fdkjfjdkfjdfkjd', 76),
(2, '100885', 2, 7, 0, 'Frank', 'Grimsley', '123 Fayke St', 76),
(5, '100886', 3, 4, 0, 'Mark', 'Hill', 'kfjdkfjdf\r\nkofjdkfjdkfdj', 76),
(6, '100887', 5, 6, 0, 'fdfdfd', 'fdfdfd', 'fdfdfdf', 76);
```

I want to create a trigger that makes it so that when I input a new row, like so

```
INSERT INTO employees(e_username,left_id,right_id,e_ssn, e_first_name, e_last_name, e_address, e_location)
VALUES('100888', 0, 0, 0, 'New','User', '100 NotReal st city, state zip', 76)
```

I want for the left_id and right_id columns to be updated based on the right_id of the first user in their location that has it's right_id differ from it's left_id by 1.

Here is what I have so far, but it gives me an error

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `after_insert_employees` ;

CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `after_insert_employees` AFTER INSERT ON  `employees` 
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
DECLARE r_id INT;
SELECT max(right_id) INTO r_id FROM employees WHERE e_location=new.e_location AND right_id = left_id+1;
UPDATE employees SET left_id = r_id+1 AND right_id = r_id+2 WHERE e_id = new.e_id;
END
```

I get this error when I try to insert something

```
 #1442 - Can't update table 'employees' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I'm lost on this one. Any help?

Comment: do you tried BEFORE Insert trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger will trying to update same table that you are inserting. MySQL will lock table when insertion is happening.

This link may help you

[MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300673/mysql-error-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-already)