# #1442 - Can't Update Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

I have created a trigger to Insert sum of all numbers in `FinalMarks` column, each time a new Record inserted in `student_marks` table.

I am getting the following error message when i am trying to insert a new record in the table.

Kindly tell me where i am making a mistake.

Thanks

Taha

-

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `insert_student` BEFORE INSERT ON `student_marks`
FOR EACH
ROW INSERT INTO student_marks( FinalMarks )
VALUES (
AssignmentMarks + QuizMarks + Hourly1 + Hourly2 + Hourly3 + ProjectMarks
)
```

**ERROR**

> ```
>   INSERT INTO `university`.`student_marks` (
> ```
>
> `StudentMarksId` ,
>   `StudentId` ,
>   `SemisterCourseId` ,
>   `AssignmentMarks` ,
>   `QuizMarks` ,
>   `Hourly1` ,
>   `Hourly2` ,
>   `Hourly3` ,
>   `FinalMarks` ,
>   `Grades` ,
>   `ProjectMarks` ,
>   `GPA`
>   )
>   VALUES (
>   NULL , '1', '1', '10', '15', '20', '15', '10', '', '', '', ''
>   )

-

> **#1442 - #1442 - Can't update table 'student_marks' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.**

Comment: As per my understanding you should use "after insert" instead of "before insert" ...

Comment: still getting the same error message

Comment: Let me get this correct.  You have shown a `before insert` trigger.  Then you get an error on an `update`.  That trigger has nothing to do with the error.

Comment: But if i remove the trigger,it works fine..

Comment: I think @jmail has answered you actually problem is that you are trying to update same table on which trigger is invoking. As trigger invoke on any event on the table it will lock the table to do the task mentioned in trigger. In this case trigger lock the table and again trying to update the same table, which is not possible. So you can achieve this by transaction..in single transaction first insert row then update desired column then either commit statement or rollback on failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 1**:

> *Its working for insertion, I also want to fire a trigger and update FinalMarks whenever Teacher Updates any Field Marks.. –  Taha Kirmani*

You also need a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger with the same `SET` logic.
But trigger name and type should be different.

**Example**:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
  TRIGGER `bu_student` BEFORE UPDATE ON `student_marks`
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    SET NEW.FinalMarks = NEW.AssignmentMarks + NEW.QuizMarks
                       + NEW.Hourly1 + NEW.Hourly2 + NEW.Hourly3 
                       + NEW.ProjectMarks;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```

---

**Original answer**:

It seems you want set a specific field `FinalMarks` a value by summing up the values being inserted. To get this done, you need not explicitly execute another `insert` statement on the table.

Instead, you can just use `SET` command for the field, in the trigger, so that it gets accepted.

**Change**:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
  TRIGGER `insert_student` BEFORE INSERT ON `student_marks`
  FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO student_marks( FinalMarks )
    VALUES (
      AssignmentMarks + QuizMarks + Hourly1 + Hourly2 + Hourly3 + ProjectMarks
    )
```

**To**:

```
CREATE DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
  TRIGGER `insert_student` BEFORE INSERT ON `student_marks`
  FOR EACH ROW 
    SET NEW.FinalMarks = NEW.AssignmentMarks + NEW.QuizMarks
                       + NEW.Hourly1 + NEW.Hourly2 + NEW.Hourly3 
                       + NEW.ProjectMarks;
```

**Refer to**:
[**MySQL: CREATE TRIGGER Syntax**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-trigger.html)
Look into one of the examples under *User Comments* on the same page.

Comment: When i am trying to do this for `before update`, its not generating any error message but its also not working..and if i change it to `after update` then it stops supporting `NEW` Keyword.

Comment: not working with `before trigger` means? what happened when issued a `insert` statement? Record is stored or not? If yes, the same values or not? Please explain.

Comment: Its working for insertion, I also want to fire a trigger and update `FinalMarks` whenever Teacher Updates any Field Marks..

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have included code snippet for `update` trigger.

Comment: Thank You so Much...Now The problem is that its not generating any error message, but its also not Updating `FinalMarks` Field..

Comment: what was the data before? what was your input? What is the data after?

Comment: I am updating data through phpmyadmin, Just inputting random numbers in `QuizMarks,AssignmentMarks,Hourly...`,  but `FinalMarks` field is not updating... Kindly check the image from the following link. http://postimg.org/image/rpf82028t/

Comment: I am not sure how you are using PHPMyAdmin. But why don't you try an `update` statement in SQL editor on it and submit. Then browse through records and see if update worked or not?

Answer (score 1):

Had to write PHP code manually to fix this.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,122354,240978#msg-240978

[MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300673/mysql-error-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-already)