# How to delete a record in a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

My trigger looks like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER addATicket AFTER INSERT ON ticket FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

declare numTicket int(2) default 0;
select count(*) into numTicket from ticket
    where (ticket.ticket_id != new.ticket_id) 
    and (ticket.seat_code = new.seat_code);

if (numTicket > 0) then
    delete from ticket where ticket_id= new.ticket_id;
end if;END
```

But my workbench catches an error:

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'ticket' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

How can I solve this problem. Please give me a help.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably because your main `INSERT` query which is firing `TRIGGER` holding a row level lock on that table and hence your trigger is complaining about the same.

most probably you want to change the trigger definition from `AFTER INSERT ON ticket` to `BEFORE INSERT ON ticket` (What I mean is use a `BEFORE TRIGGER` instead).

See a almost similar post here

[MySql Error: Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300673/mysql-error-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-already)