# MySQL Error 1442

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

> `sanction` with these attributes: `DriverID`, `Calification`, `Points`
>   `people`  with these attributes: `pID`, `city` , `TotalPoints`

And i have this trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS updatePoints_tgr;

delimiter $$
CREATE  TRIGGER
updatePoints_tgr AFTER UPDATE
ON sanctions FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
     if NEW.points > OLD.points 
     THEN
         UPDATE people
         SET TotalPoints = TotalPoints + (NEW.points - OLD.points)
         WHERE people.pID = NEW.DriverID;
     elseif NEW.points < OLD.points 
     THEN
         UPDATE people
         SET TotalPoints = TotalPoints - (NEW.points - OLD.points)
         WHERE people.pID = NEW.DriverID;
     END IF;
 END$$
 delimiter ;
```

And when I try to execute this update

```
UPDATE sanctions 
JOIN people ON sanctions.DriverID=people.pID
SET points=points+6
WHERE city='Barcelona'  AND Calification='LightPenalty'
```

I  get this error:

> Can't update table 'people' in stored function/trigger because it is
>   already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

How can i fix it? Thanks.

I use Windows 10 and MySQL server 5.7.17

Comment: I'm not an expert at this, but I don't think you can.... which, to be fair, is a little surprising for an `AFTER UPDATE`.

Comment: Windows 10, Version 6.3.8 build 1228 CE (64 bits)

Comment: We can try to prove (using the bug tracker) that it's not a bug specific to that version (or maybe it is!) but instead an expected behaviour. I will come back to this question a bit later and see what I can find if nobody beats me to it, because it's interesting.

Comment: yes, sorry. MySQL server 5.7.17

Comment: Do not you have another trigger, on `people` table?

Comment: Ahead of time, here's some vaguely related information confirming my suspicions (ish): http://stackoverflow.com/q/15300673/560648

Comment: No, I have no trigger on people.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition In that question it is using the same table on the trigger and on the update inside of the trigger. (Sorry if i am not explaining myself clearly), and I think that is not my case.

Comment: @J.Coe: I said vaguely

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update a table (`sanctions` and `people`) where the trigger is invoked:

> Within a stored function or trigger, it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

Doing so will generate Error 1442:

```
Error Code: 1442
Can't update table 'MyTable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

---

**Your case**: The confusion can be due to the `JOIN` on `sanctions` and `people` for the `UPDATE` - making both the table in use, as stated above '**used**' means '**reading or writing**'.

---

To test - Try the `UPDATE` query without the `JOIN` (with `people`) - if it works, surely it is the case.