# How do I update a table inside an INSERT trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I'm a newbie to SQL and I have to write a trigger that checks if there is enough product stock for new orders. Also if the order quantity is greater than a certain number I need to update the discount row.

But apparently you are not allowed to update a table from an INSERT trigger. How do I go about doing this?

This is what I've written so far

```html
DELIMITER //
create trigger before_order before insert on order_detail FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare stock_remain int;
    declare ord_quantity int;
    declare inventory int;
    declare price int;
    declare p_id int;
    declare ord_id int;
    select product_id into @p_id from order_detail where product_id = new.product_id;
          
    select unit_price into @price from order_detail where unit_price = new.unit_price;

    select order_detail_id into @ord_id from order_detail where order_detail_id = new.order_detail_id;
          
    SET @stock_remain=est_remaining_stock(@price, @p_id);
    select quantity into @ord_quantity from order_detail where order_detail_id=@ord_id;
    SET @inventory = @stock_remain - @ord_quantity;
    IF @inventory < 10 THEN
    
    signal sqlstate '45001' set message_text = "No way ! You cannot do this !";
     
    END IF;

    IF @ord_quantity > 40 THEN
    
    UPDATE order_detail SET new.discount = 5 where product_id=new.product_id;

     
    END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: i think you need to use BEFORE INSERT and SET like said on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300673/mysql-error-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-already

Answer (score 0):

1. **Noway** to alter the data in the table where the trigger is defined on. But you may alter the data to be saved into the table.
2. `DECLARE variable` and `SELECT INTO @variable` uses two **different** variables.
3. A bunch of variables can be set on one SELECT INTO statement.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER before_order 
BEFORE INSERT ON order_detail 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare stock_remain int;
    declare ord_quantity int;
    declare inventory int;
    declare price int;
    declare p_id int;
    declare ord_id int;

    select product_id, unit_price, order_detail_id 
        into p_id, price, ord_id
        from order_detail 
        where product_id = new.product_id;          
          
    SET stock_remain=est_remaining_stock(price, p_id);

    select quantity 
        into ord_quantity 
        from order_detail 
        where order_detail_id=@ord_id;
    SET inventory = stock_remain - ord_quantity;
    IF inventory < 10 THEN
        signal sqlstate '45001' set message_text = "No way ! You cannot do this !";
    END IF;
    IF ord_quantity > 40 THEN
        SET new.discount = 5;
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can DECLARE a list of same datatype variables in a single DECLARE statement. I finally commented it, because these variables are not used in the trigger (use of user defined variable starting with @ which is perfectly fine).
2. you may take into account several rows with the same product id may exists  in the new order : reason why I'm proposing to use a SUM on order quantity.
3. keep in mind the SET new.<column_name> statement in the trigger will be executed FOR EACH ROW inserted so you should not do an UPDATE ... WHERE ...
4. I may suggest your error message to be more informative about inventory to low to satisfy the order for this product.

```sql
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_order BEFORE INSERT ON order_detail ;

    DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER before_order BEFORE INSERT ON order_detail FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        -- DECLARE stock_remain, ord_quantity, inventory, price, p_id, ord_id INT ;

        SET @stock_remain=est_remaining_stock(new.unit_price, new.product_id);

        SELECT SUM(quantity) INTO @ord_quantity 
        FROM order_detail 
        WHERE order_detail_id = new.order_detail_id 
        AND product_id = new.product_id ;

        SET @inventory := (@stock_remain - @ord_quantity) ;

        IF @inventory < 10 THEN
          SIGNAL sqlstate '45001' SET message_text := "No way ! You cannot do this !";
        END IF;

        IF @ord_quantity > 40 THEN
          SET new.discount := 5 ;
        END IF;

    END//
    DELIMITER ;
```