# How to maintain integrity between two columns on a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, integrity

I have columns which are `a primary key` and `a plain column` on `a table`. I want to maintain `integrity` about two columns.

Suppose I have a user table and two datas. I want to have `integrity` between a `id` column and a `create_user` column

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
    id varchar(10) not null,
    create_user varchar(10) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into USER (id,create_user) values ('system','system');
insert into USER (id,create_user) values ('user01','system');

The result is

| id       | create_user |
| -------- | ------------|
| system   | system      |
| user01   | system      |
```

If I update id(a primary key), It doesn't have integrity.

```
update USER SET id='master' WHERE id='system';

The result is

| id       | create_user |
| -------- | ------------|
| master   | system      |
| user01   | system      |
```

But **I want to this** on `a table`. Is it possible? I don't want additional update queris

```
| id       | create_user |
| -------- | ------------|
| master   | master      |
| user01   | master      |
```

Comment: and you dont want to write ```triggers```?

Comment: @IbrahimHammed No, I only don't want that the user should remember additional task for that.

Comment: @Carmel User will use system as previously, triggers works automatically

Comment: Why would you need to update a primary key value? That's not something you normally do... Also what is `create_user` and what's it's relation to the primary key ?

Comment: @Justinas I tried the trigger. But It doesn't work, I get a error "Can't update table in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger". Because I use the trigger for same table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300673/mysql-error-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-already

Comment: @SOS the create_user column shows who makes the data on USER table. So, I have better not think that a primary key is not changed? the foreign key has "UPDATE CASCADE". Because I think a primary key can be changed, rarely.

Comment: @SOS in my case, I want to change id of system admin from system to master.

Comment: You must provide your "integrity" definition. Create verbal definition which sets this integrity rule completely. PS. Now this can be easily solved by additional *values* table.

Comment: @SOS Thank you for your advice. "a PK (primary key) is to have a unique identifying value that doesn't change, so it shouldn't be modified", "he value user01 isn't a good choice for a PK". I will change pk from id to no!

Comment: @Carmel - Sorry I accidentally deleted my comment instead of edit.  Not sure I follow what you're saying... However, if I'm understanding the table structure correctly, then `id` as the PK, should be an unique value, like an `auto_increment` column.  The username i.e. "user01" should be stored in a separate column, possibly with a unique index.  If `create_user` column contains a user `id` value, then it should be a nullable numeric column.  For example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1a6b0b5e4e0b7cf1274ab1bc9148eca7

Comment: You have a logical inconsistency you could create a foreign key on create_user referencing id with on update cascade but and update will throw an error because mysql checks that system exists as id before attempting the change. And it seems myasql will ignore on update cascade if set foreign_key_checks are set to off.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69373faba07b7a8c0f45400d2787e630

Answer (score 0):

You can update as many columns as you like and use case statements to decide what to set them to

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t (
    id varchar(10) not null,
    create_user varchar(10) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into t (id,create_user) values ('system','system');
insert into t (id,create_user) values ('user01','system');

update t
SET id = case when id= 'system' then 'master' else id end ,
    create_user = case when create_user = 'system' then 'master' else create_user end 
where id = 'system' or create_user = 'system';

select * from t;

+--------+-------------+
| id     | create_user |
+--------+-------------+
| master | master      |
| user01 | master      |
+--------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```