# Use Procedure instead of trigger in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make trigger to update one field in inserted row but even with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300941/4018940 i cant make it work.

Every time i get error:

> General error: 1442 Can't update table 'people' in stored
> function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked
> this stored function/trigger

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER short_name_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON `people`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE `people` SET NEW.short_name = "wohahaha";
END
```

Is there any chance that stored procedure will make it work?
How to write that procedure?

Comment: You're trying to update the same table that the trigger is defined on within the trigger itself, that creates a circular reference which is not allowed in `MySQL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the value being inserted in the new row, you don't need to use `UPDATE people`. Just set `NEW.short_name` and this will replace the value that's being inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER short_name_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON `people`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.short_name = "wohahaha";
END
```