# Do not update another field with trigger after update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I create one trigger from Mysql and my targer is when has update value of filed extpoint2 trigger will update value of filed
left_coin and set value of this to: `left_coin + ( new.extpoint2 - old.extpoint2 )`;

and this is my trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_left_coin AFTER UPDATE ON account_zone
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF !(NEW.extpoint_2 <=> OLD.extpoint_2) THEN
      UPDATE account_zone SET account_zone.left_coin = case WHEN NEW.extpoint_2 then account_zone.left_coin ELSE account_zone.left_coin + (NEW.extpoint_2 - OLD.extpoint_2) END;
   END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

but when I update value for filed **extpoint2 **
this return error massage:

> 1442 - Can't update table 'account_zone' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
> How to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change a table while the UPDATE trigger is firing

However, depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can access the new values by using `NEW.left_coin` or even the old values --if doing an UPDATE-- with OLD.

So you would

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_left_coin
BEFORE UPDATE ON account_zone
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.extpoint_2 <> OLD.extpoint_2 THEN
        SET NEW.left_coin = OLD.left_coin + (NEW.extpoint_2 - OLD.extpoint_2);
    END IF;
END;
//DELIMITER ;
```

[and you can see the same question with link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300673/mysql-error-cant-update-table-in-stored-function-trigger-because-it-is-already)

Answer (score 0):

You can not update the same row that invoked the trigger in an `AFTER` Trigger, you need to change it in a `BEFORE TRIGGER`

So you would

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_left_coin BEFORE UPDATE ON account_zone
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF !(NEW.extpoint_2 <=> OLD.extpoint_2) THEN
      NEW.left_coin = case WHEN NEW.extpoint_2 then NEW.left_coin ELSE NEW.left_coin + (NEW.extpoint_2 - OLD.extpoint_2) END;
   END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```