# Replace word in mysql with same word but uppercase

Tags: mysql, replace, uppercase

For example:

I have text in my column like: 'some text with word to replace' and i want to replace:

word with Word

i do:

```
update table set column = replace(column, 'word', 'Word');
```

and i get error:

> Mysql: #1442 - Can't update table 'table' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: do you see create trigger in here?

Comment: @pain-reign I see the correct answer on that question

Comment: @Tuga so what query i should run to do my job if you see an answer )

Comment: @pain-reign http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/update.php

Comment: @pain-reign is the `table` name also `table` ?

Comment: @Tuga no, i just replaced the table name. Well i know how update statements work. I gave you the query, and it doesn't work what can you suggest?

Comment: @pain-reign check this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582683/mysql-trigger-stored-trigger-is-already-used-by-statement-which-invoked-stored-t

Comment: @Tuga I checked all those before creating new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change only the first letter :

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET myColumn = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(myColumn, 1)), SUBSTRING(myColumn, 2));
```

If you want to change all the column :

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET myColumn = UPPER(myColumn);
```

If you want to replace some words, you have to use the replace function :

```
UPDATE MyTable SET myColumn = replace(myColumn, 'word', 'Word');
```

Please to consider to accept my answer if it's OK for you.

**EDIT :** Adding a third example to search and replace a word in the field and replace it to another one.

Comment: First example: 'Some text with word to replace' second example: 'SOME TEXT WITH WORD TO REPLACE' required: 'some text with Word to replace' do you see any difference?

Comment: My third example should do the trick. For example, it will replace all 'word' elements to 'Word' for each rows.

Comment: Did you add this to a trigger ?! It seems MySQL doesn't allow to update in a update trigger due to infinite loop problem.

Comment: Yeah i didn't add it to the trigger i will try it tomorrow and let you know

Comment: I didn't really test it but i suppose it would work with trigger. Just its out of scope for me now. So i cannot accept your answer because the query as you showed doesn't work. But i will +1 you for trigger hint.

Answer (score 0):

Use UPPER or LOWER functions in mysql.

Comment: Can you give an example? if i use upper or lower it will replace whole line but i need to replace only certain word in line with uppercase first letter

Comment: I misunderstood the question, but if it is the message you are trying to fix, try putting sware brackets around the table and field names.