# Can't figure out where this trigger is looping ERROR #1442 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Hey guys i'm doing a website that generates, multiple types of tournaments and i keep getting this error on phpmyadmin when i try to update the "punteggio(point)" column on my database so that it can automatically generate the next phase of the tournament, i believe the trigger is looping but i can't figure out where.

I'm using the phpmyadmin gui interface to create the triggers.

this error pops up only when i enable the second trigger, The first one works fine without the second one.

This is the error

> #1442 - Can't update table 'Partecipa' in stored function/trigger
>   because     it is already used by statement which invoked this stored
>   function/trigger.

Translations:

**Gara = match;

Torneo = tournament;

punteggio = point

vincitori = Winners

fase = phase**

TRIGGER FUNCTION I(AFTER UPDATE ON Partecipa) :This function will be Triggered after a punteggio( or point) is updated

```
BEGIN 

    SET @garamodificata = NEW.Gara_id_Gara;

    SET @punteggio = (SELECT Punteggio FROM Partecipa WHERE Gara_id_Gara = @garamodificata AND Punteggio != NEW.Punteggio );

    SET @verifica = (SELECT Id_gara FROM Vincitori WHERE Id_gara = @garamodificata);
    SET @verificaEliminazioneDiretta = (SELECT Tipo_torneo FROM Torneo WHERE Id_torneo = NEW.Gara_Torneo_Id_torneo);


IF(@verificaEliminazioneDiretta = "Eliminazione Diretta") THEN

    IF(@verifica IS NULL ) THEN 
        IF(@punteggio > NEW.Punteggio) THEN 
            SET @giocatore = (SELECT Giocatore_id_Giocatore FROM Partecipa WHERE Gara_id_Gara = @garamodificata AND Punteggio = @punteggio);
            INSERT INTO Vincitori(Id_gara,Id_giocatore)VALUES(@garamodificata,@giocatore);

        ELSEIF(@punteggio < NEW.Punteggio) THEN 
            SET @giocatore = (SELECT Giocatore_id_Giocatore FROM Partecipa WHERE Gara_id_Gara = @garamodificata AND Punteggio = NEW.Punteggio);
            INSERT INTO Vincitori(Id_gara,Id_giocatore)VALUES(@garamodificata,@giocatore);
        END IF;

        ELSE 
        IF(@punteggio> NEW.Punteggio) THEN 
            SET @giocatore = (SELECT Giocatore_id_Giocatore FROM Partecipa WHERE Gara_id_Gara = @garamodificata AND Punteggio = @punteggio);
            UPDATE Vincitori SET Id_giocatore = @giocatore WHERE Id_gara = @garamodificata;

        ELSEIF(@punteggio < NEW.Punteggio) THEN 
            SET @giocatore = (SELECT Giocatore_id_Giocatore FROM Partecipa WHERE Gara_id_Gara = @garamodificata AND Punteggio = NEW.Punteggio);
            UPDATE Vincitori SET Id_giocatore = @giocatore WHERE Id_gara = @garamodificata;
        END IF;

    END IF;
END IF;

END
```

TRIGGER FUNCTION(AFTER INSERT TRIGGER ON Vincitori) : this function inserts in partecipa the new matches of the next phase and it is an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER ON Vincitori

```
BEGIN 


SET @fase = (SELECT MAX(Fase)FROM Partecipa WHERE Gara_id_Gara = NEW.Id_gara); #phase of the tournament
SET @torneo = (SELECT Torneo_Id_torneo From Gara WHERE id_Gara = NEW.Id_gara); #id of the tournament 
SET @expectedResults = (SELECT COUNT(*)FROM Partecipa WHERE  Fase = @fase AND Gara_Torneo_Id_torneo = @torneo)/2; #number of results needed to generate next phase
SET @actualResults =(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Vincitori INNER JOIN Partecipa ON Vincitori.Id_gara = Partecipa.Gara_id_Gara WHERE Partecipa.Gara_Torneo_Id_torneo = @torneo AND Partecipa.Fase = @fase)/2;
#numberof results in Vincitori 

SET @i = 1;
SET @j = 2;


IF(@expectedResults = @actualResults) THEN

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE gare(id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, id_giocatore VARCHAR(45),id_gara INT(11));
    INSERT INTO gare(id_giocatore,id_gara)
    SELECT DISTINCT Vincitori.id_giocatore,Vincitori.id_Gara
    FROM Vincitori INNER JOIN Partecipa ON Vincitori.Id_gara = Partecipa.Gara_id_Gara WHERE Partecipa.Gara_Torneo_Id_torneo = @torneo;


    SET @garedagenerare = (@actualResults/2)+1;
    SET @fase = @fase + 1;   

    WHILE (@i < @garedagenerare) DO
        SET @idprossimagara = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(id_gara) FROM gare);
        SET @idprossimagara = (@idprossimagara + 1);
        SET @datagara = (SELECT DISTINCT Data_gara FROM Gara WHERE id_Gara = @idprossimagara); 

        SET @Player1 = (SELECT DISTINCT id_giocatore FROM gare WHERE id = @i);
        SET @Player2 = (SELECT DISTINCT id_giocatore FROM gare WHERE id = @j);

        INSERT INTO Partecipa VALUES(@Player1,@idprossimagara,@torneo,0,@datagara,@fase);
        INSERT INTO Partecipa VALUES(@Player2,@idprossimagara,@torneo,0,@datagara,@fase);

        SET @i = @i+2;
        SET @j = @j+2;

    END WHILE;

END IF;


END
```

Comment: [MySQL triggers can't manipulate the table they are assigned to.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2314264/3603374). You cannot insert in table `Partecipa` inside trigger.

Comment: so any suggestions on what i can do now ?